# Computing a list containing the numbers from x to y

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I create a method which takes two numbers and prepare a list from first number to second number.  The first number is always positive and less than second number?  I tried the following but the I am not sure how to have a global variable in Scheme to hold previous values.

```
(define preplist  
  (let ((temp '())) 
   (lambda (x y) 
     (cond ((= x y) (append temp (list x)))
           (else (append temp (list x))
                 (display x)
                 (preplist (+ x 1) y))))))
```

Expected result is: (preplist 3 7) => (3 4 5 6 7)

Can some one please help to resolve this problem?

Comment: Side comment: this is a built-in procedure in Racket: it's called `range`.  http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._range%29%29

Answer (score 1):

The solution for (x, y) can be computed as: put x on the front of (x+1, y). It is thus clearly recursive.  Like this:

```
(define (preplist x y)
  (if (= x y)
      (list y)
      (cons x (preplist (+ x 1) y))))
```

See, it works:

```
> (preplist 1 4)
(1 2 3 4)
> (preplist 5 7)
(5 6 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your code, for starters you don't need a global variable defined in a `let` for storing the result, it's enough to build the answer as you advance in the recursion. And don't use `append` in this case, if the solution template is followed closely, a `cons` will suffice for building the output list.

You should stick to the recipe for building a new list recursively; this is how the problem should be solved using that recipe, it's perhaps a bit more idiomatic like this:

```
(define preplist
  (lambda (x y)
    (cond ((> x y)                          ; if the exit condition is met
           empty)                           ; then return the empty list
          (else                             ; otherwise
           (cons x                          ; cons the current element
                 (preplist (add1 x) y)))))) ; and advance the recursion
```

An altogether  different approach would be to write a tail-recursive solution. This is more efficient because a constant amount of stack is used. It doesn't follow the design recipe as outlined above, but is somewhat more similar to the solution you had in mind - but bear in mind that this doesn't use global variables (only a named `let` for the iteration) and the solution is accumulated and passed around as a parameter:

```
(define (preplist x y)
  (let loop ((i y)             ; named let for iteration
             (acc empty))      ; define and initialize parameters
    (if (> x i)                ; if exit condition is met
        acc                    ; return accumulated value
        (loop (sub1 i)         ; otherwise advance recursion
              (cons i acc))))) ; and add to the accumulator
```

Of course, as pointed by @dyoo in the comments, in a practical setting you'd use the built-in [`range`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=range#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._range%29%29) procedure which does basically the same as the `preplist` procedure.